# TCP client and server supporting six simple commands

Tags: python, beginner, homework, tcp

For a class, I was given an assignment to code a simple TCP connection between a server and a client. Once the TCP handshake is done, the client sends inquiries to the server. It's a 2 second conversation, if that.
I need some feedback on my code. Please keep in mind that I am new to Python. The prof kinda threw the class to the wolves on this.

This is the server code:

```
import socket
import time
import sys
#from thread import *

def Main():
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 8008


        s.bind((host, port))


        print ("Port, that's a wine right? " + str(port))

        s.listen(1)
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ("200 SRP version 1.0 ready")
        print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            data = str(data).upper()
            print ("sending: " + str(data))
            c.send(data)            
            print ("from connected user: " + str(data))
            print ("Welcome, would you like a jelly baby?")

            if not data:
                        break
            if True:
                if data.startswith('HELO'):
                    try:
                        c.sendall("210 HELO " +  host + " This is Dalek High Command. You will obey all orders without question!")
                    except:
                        c.sendall("510 You are unauthorized! You will be exterminated!")
                    break
                elif data.startswith('REQTIME'):
                    try:
                        c.sendall ("220 I obey!  The time is " + time.strftime("%H%:M%:S"))
                    except:
                        c.sendall ("520 The time is unavailable!  Exterminate!")
                        break
                elif data.startswith('REQDATE'):
                        try:
                        c.sendall ("230 I obey!  The date is " + time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
                    except:
                        c.sendall ("530 The date is unavailable!  Exterminate!")
                        break
                elif data.startswith('ECHO'):
                    try:
                        data = str(data).upper()
                        c.sendall ("240 Data received! " + data)
                    except:
                        c.sendall ("540 ECHO!  I cannot obey!  Assist!  Assist!  Cannot comply!  Exterminate!")
                        break
                elif data.startswith('REQIP'):
                    try:
                        c.sendall ("250 IP has been identified! " + host)
                    except:
                        c.sendall ("550 Alert!  I cannot obey! Your IP cannot be retrieved!")
                        break
                elif data.startswith('BYE'):
                    try:
                        c.sendall ("600 Alonzy! Bowties are cool!  See you later!")
                    except:
                        break
sys.exit()
c.close()
```

This is the client:

```
import socket

def Main():
        host = ''
        port = 8008

        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((host, port))

        message = s.recv(1024)
        print('Received from server: ' + str(data))


        for x in range(0, 5):
            if x == 0:
                data = 'helo'
                s.send(data)
            elif x == 1: 
                data = 'reqtime'
            elif x == 2:
                data = 'reqdate'
            elif x == 3:    
                data = 'echo'
            elif x == 4:
                data = 'reqid'
            elif x == 5:
                data = 'bye'

        s.send(data)
        print(str(data))
        x = x + 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Code! Good job on your first question.

Comment: So does it look okay, @SirPython?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I've tested them locally and I keep getting an indentation error on the server on line 46.  I'm using Notepad++ and all my indents look fine.  I use tabs instead of the Spacebar.

c.sendall ("230 I obey!  The date is " + time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))

Comment: @Shannon: You need to un-indent the line above that.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.

PEP 8 [says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation):

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

You use four spaces in some places, but in others you use eight.  At the very *least* you should be consistent, but it is best if you consistently use four spaces.  In fact, looking at your code, your indentation is completely shot.  I spy with my little eye an `IndentationError` in the `elif data.startswith('REQDATE'):` block.  Your `break` statements in those `if` blocks are not consistent either.

> ```
> print("sending: " + str(data))
> ```

One line up you defined `data` as a string.  Python objects don't just drift into new types.  They don't change unless you change them.  You don't need the `str` part here.  Just do this:

```
print("sending: " + data)
```

You convert `data` to a string in several other places, but there also it is useless.  That's like translating a German sentence into English and then translating *that* sentence into English every time I want to use it.  What is the purpose of translating English into English?

> ```
> if True:
> ```

`True` is always `True`, so that `if` block will always be executed.  Why do you use an `if` block if you always want to execute what is inside?

> ```
> if data.startswith('HELO'):
>     try:
>         c.sendall(...)
>     except:
>         c.sendall(...)
>     break
> elif data.startswith('REQTIME'):
>     try:
>         c.sendall(...)
>     except:
>         c.sendall(...)
>         break
> ...
> ```

You have some duplicate code there.  That is, it would be duplicate if you were consistent with what you wanted.  There are two things that change in these: The string given to the first `c.sendall()` and the string given to the second `c.sendall()`.  I would create a dictionary:

```
messages = {
    'HELO': (
        "210 HELO " + host + " This is Dalek High Command.  You will obey all orders without question!",
        "510 You are unauthorized! You will be exterminated!"),
    'REQTIME': (
        "220 I obey!  The time is " + time.strftime("%H%:M%:S"),
        "520 The time is unavailable!  Exterminate!"),
    'REQDATE': (
        "230 I obey!  The date is " + time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"),
        "530 The date is unavailable!  Exterminate!"),
    'ECHO': (
        "240 Data received! " + data.upper(),
        "540 ECHO!  I cannot obey!  Assist!  Assist!  Cannot comply!  Exterminate!"),
    'REQIP': (
        "250 IP has been identified! " + host,
        "550 Alert!  I cannot obey! Your IP cannot be retrieved!"),
}

for key, value in messages.items():
    if data.startswith(key):
        try:
            c.sendall(value[0])
        except:
            c.sendall(value[1])
        break
else:
    if data.startswith('BYE'):
        try:
            c.sendall ("600 Alonzy! Bowties are cool!  See you later!")
        except:
            break
```

> ```
> sys.exit()
> c.close()
> ```

You exit the program and then expect to be able to close `c`?  Perhaps that's a debugging call that you forgot to take out, but `sys.exit()` is unnecessary here.

> ```
> for x in range(0, 5):
>     if x == 0:
>         data = 'helo'
>         s.send(data)
>     elif x == 1: 
>         data = 'reqtime'
>     elif x == 2:
>         data = 'reqdate'
>     elif x == 3:    
>         data = 'echo'
>     elif x == 4:
>         data = 'reqid'
>     elif x == 5:
>         data = 'bye'
>
> s.send(data)
> print(str(data))
> x = x + 1
> ```

I'm guessing that the `s.send(data)` and below lines were meant to be inside of the `for` loop.  If they were, there is a much simpler way to do this:

```
for data in ("helo", "reqtime", "reqdate", "echo", "reqid", "bye"):
    s.send(data)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The sequence

```
    try:
        sendall(...)
    except:
        sendall(...)
```

doesn't look right. The `except` clause is executed when `sendall` threw the exception. The exception is most likely caused to the network problem, so there is a big chance that the second `sendall` will also fail. Even more important is misattribution. For example, in

```
        try:
            c.sendall("210 HELO " +  host + " This is Dalek High Command. You will obey all orders without question!")
        except:
            c.sendall("510 You are unauthorized! You will be exterminated!")
```

the exception is raised by *your* attempt to send, yet you are going to exterminate the *user* (who apparently did nothing wrong).

I can also make an educated guess that the server is not supposed to execute any command until the client sends `helo`.

Comment: Do I really need to explain the 'exterminate' thing?